# How to recieve call in C# from Xlite sip phone?

Tags: c#, asterisk

How I can receive call from sip phone in c# using asterisk.net library?

(how create an extension in c# and how listener event trigger using asterisk.net DLL )

Simple is that I want listen a call from sip phone in c# using asterisk server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to receive call event you can use asterisk.net library but if you want to call through your app and making call you have to use webrtc. 
you can find WebRTC document here: [WebRTC.org](http://www.webrtc.org/)
Asterisk has had support for WebRTC since version 11.